# Colapsar Barra de Menu Automaticamente con jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Que tal amigos en esta ocasion necesito que al salir del menu con el evento `mouseout();` este se colapse automaticamente pero no logra hacer eso, ya le asigne un id a cada elemento del menu, que estoy haciendo mal?

```
 $("#collapse").on("click", function(){

    });

    $("#side-bar").mouseout(function() {
        $("#collapse").on("click");
    });
```

Aca dejo la imagen del menu y de su codigo respectivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Menu Colapsado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de el menu y del boton que colapsa:

Menu:

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-black sidebar-mini">
    <!-- Site wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="main-header">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" class="logo">
                <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
                <span class="logo-mini"><b>S</b>V</span>
                <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
                <span class="logo-lg"><b>Sistema de Ventas</b></span>
            </a>
            <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button" id="collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <!-- Notifications: style can be found in dropdown.less -->

                        <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>img/logo_sol_futu.png" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                                <span class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $this->session->userdata("nombre")?></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="user-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.row -->
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Este es del boton que colapsa:

```
            <li class="header">Menu</li>
                  <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
                <div class="user-panel">
                    <div class="pull-left image">

                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left info">

                  <p><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> En Linea</p>
                </div>
              </div>

            <?php echo $this->backend_lib->getMenu();?>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta cambiando el **mouseout** por **mouseleave** y hazle un **trigger** a **#collapse** en el evento **mouseleave** así:

```
$("#side-bar").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#collapse").trigger("click");
});
```

Con el **trigger** le estas indicando que ejecute un evento de un tercero. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Si funciono, pero cada vez que coloco el mouse encima se vuelve loco el menu

Comment: que extraño te hace? se cierra varias veces?

Comment: Si asi es cada vez que regreso al menu se abre y se colapsa

Comment: Intenta cambiadno el mouseout por el mouseleave a ver y me cuentas

Comment: Listo funciono a la perfeccion gracias amigo

Comment: Voy a modificar mi respuesta para que por favor la tildes como ganadora, muchas gracias